# Codeigniter Deployed on IP Address Gives 404 On Every Controller Except Index

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I just deployed CI on an IP address on Amazon Server. I have set my default_controller to a custom controller. All my controller names are in capital letters and file names are capital too. However every other controller except default controller gives 404 error. All the assets and views etc are loading fine. Only the controllers are giving 404 errors. I have double checked all the file names and controller names and everything is fine. I have no idea what is causing this. Mod rewrite on the server is enabled too.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

- Mod Rewrite Enabled
- Controllers and Models Names Capital
- File Names Capital

Url is [website url](http://34.247.49.130)

Ahmar.

Comment: `All my controller names are in capital letters and file names are capital too.` - are your urls capitalized as well.,

Comment: Urls are not captilazied but /Home doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Try set empty value to **index_page** in your **config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**UPDATE**

Try update your htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So what about adding **RewriteBase /** to your htaccess ?

Comment: Can you post example ht access